# Android Autocomplete custom adapter view

Tags: android, autocomplete, adapter

Autocomplete in android makes easier to pick an item from the search text, i used listview for my previous project and it did quiet simple, in my new project i want to make something different view for autocomplete result, i did a Google for a some functionality but no luck.
I got a screenshot of a popular application, they have used different style,
like this,
[image: autocompletesearch]

how to achieve this? is there any library available? Helps appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many available. I would recommend [android-chips](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) . There is a working example of this under [samples folder](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips/tree/master/src/com/android/ex/chips/sample).

Comment: But android-chips is look like the list is displaying in same style as listview does.. i need the list like my screenshot picture.. the list items are in blue background and auto aligned based on width of the text..

Comment: you should download the source and modify it. or you can make your own.

Comment: That's wat am asking the start, i can make a dynamic view of textview when the list generated after started typing keywords, but the layout linear does not auto align the view when it exceeds the screen..